# Customers automatically logged in as a different customer

Tags: php, opencart, e-commerce, opencart2.x

I have three Open Cart installations on the same server. 
It's like

> www.myshop.com/shop1; www.myshop.com/shop2; www.myshop.com/shop3`

They share the same `MySQL DB` with different prefixes.

The problem now is that sometimes a customer is automatically logged in as a different customer. He can even see the history of the user.

I have figured out what the reason actually is: If a user

AB has the user ID 10 in Shop 1 and 
if the user CD has the same ID (10) in Shop 2,

then the error occurs.

User AB from Shop 1 will see the account of user CD if he visits Shop 2.

So it is a session problem. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Okay I have figured out what the reason actually is:
If a user AB has the user ID 10 in Shop 1 and if the user CD has the same ID (10) in Shop 2 then the error occurs. User AB from Shop 1 will see the account of user CD if he visits Shop 2. So it is a session problem. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Seko, could you add this information to your question?

Comment: Hi Matthew, Thanks for the info.  I have edited my question.

Comment: @Seko : Shop 1, shop 2 and shop 3 have a same `DB`, it means All three have same `DB` named `xyz`?

Comment: Yes right @zedBlackbeard. But they have different prefixes like shop1_table, shop2_table, shop3_table

Answer (score 0):

Why are u using different table in same database?
Opencart offers different store facility inbuilt. There is a table `'table_prefix'.store` . You can override your each store in same database and same tables.
Ok if you use same database but your each store act as different Opencart Installations.
I think you might be facing some issue like switching different store by a single customer and transfer product etc.